# Datepart in store procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

For the following query, I have to compare mm part of each @currentdate and @workingdatekey. How to compare only mm part from yyyymmdd format? If the Month  of @workingdatekey is same as the month of the @currentdate continue else exit

```
Declare @currentdate int
set @currentdate =  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE(),112))
print @currentdate


Declare @workingdatekey int
set @workingdatekey =  CONVERT(int,CONVERT(varchar(20),GETDATE()-1,112))
print @workingdatekey
```

Comment: Is this question about SQL Server or MySQL? Tags are confusing. Check MONTH() function. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IF (MONTH(GETDATE()-1) = MONTH(GETDATE()))
 BEGIN
   /* DO something here */
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  /* Else do something here*/
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you convert those values to a varchar? If not, you can do datepart(mm, "your date column"). That will return the month of the date. You can then do:

```
if datepart(mm, "currentdatekey") = datepart(mm, "workingdatekey")
      print 'They matched'
else
      print 'They are different'
```